# Random Access Iterator to char array

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

Is it possible to use `std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag, const char*>` as an iterator over a char array? Looking at the `std::iterator` definition it only has default, copy and move constructors, no `T` constructor. Would this mean I'd need to inherit and implement my own iterator?

Comment: `const char*` already is an iterator (or const_iterator), so you really don't have to inherit anything to get there. `std::iterator` might be used as a base class when building other iterator classes, but that is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::iterator` can't help you as is. It's true that you could inherit from it to implement your own iterator, but you can already use pointers into the array as random-access iterators.

You can even use `std::begin` and `std::end` to get those iterators.

Comment: What if I simply have a const char* and a std::size_t rather than a std::array?

Comment: @Graeme I think you're looking for `[p, p + size)` as a range in that case. This relies on the values for `p` and `size` being correct.